# Purpose of WCF to WCF Call?

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I am new to WCF. while Searching google i heard the concept **WCF to WCF call**.

As I know WCF is Web Service. So multiple clients may make use of it. But don't know why we would use a WCF to WCF call.

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean by "WCF to WCF call". If you just mean one service calling another service, then why not? WCF services are just programs, if they happen to need information from a different service, what else should they do?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield If I had to guess he would have heard about it in the context of [`ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode(v=vs.110).aspx) where WCF allows new calls to be processed while you are waiting for another external WCF service to reply. (But until the OP replies, it is only a guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A given WCF service may need to call upon the services of one or more other WCF services in order to get things done.

A simple example is that an order processing service may need to use the services of a logging service and an email service.

Comment: For the purposes of `ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant` (the only other place I have ever heard "WCF to WCF" used before) the much more common use of the callback channel and waiting for its response is also considered a "Call to another service".

Comment: Almost everywhere I've worked with WCF services have focused on a SOA (Service Oriented Architecture). In this case, it is almost always the case that one service will use the services of more than one service. This allows for something like the "Single Responsibility Principal", where a service focuses on doing one thing very well. It also aids in scaling, where some services which may be used heavily can be installed on faster servers, and possibly a set of load-balanced servers.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly what you are refereeing to is Duplex WCF Service where both client and server are WCF. If you have a scenario where client and server both needs to notify each other of some event than that is a good case for duplex WCF service. There is a callback pattern with duplex WCF which means client for example notify server that call me back when event X occur. Server remembers that and call back client when event X occur.

[MSDN-Duplex Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)